# How do I get the build job jobid property from the AppVeyor API via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have obtained this JSON from the AppVeyor API:

```
 $build = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://ci.appveyor.com/api/projects/XXX/XXX/branch/master | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I need to look at this array:

```
$build.build.jobs
```

Which returns:

```
jobId                    : jgc1moa0o1tjdkyq
name                     : Environment: PYTHON=C:\Python35, PYTHON_VERSION=3.5.x, PYTHON_ARCH=32
allowFailure             : False
messagesCount            : 0
compilationMessagesCount : 0
compilationErrorsCount   : 0
compilationWarningsCount : 0
testsCount               : 0
passedTestsCount         : 0
failedTestsCount         : 0
artifactsCount           : 1
status                   : success
started                  : 2017-03-23T08:34:59.2087897+00:00
finished                 : 2017-03-23T08:37:03.7539463+00:00
created                  : 2017-03-23T08:34:52.1106626+00:00
updated                  : 2017-03-23T08:37:03.7539463+00:00

jobId                    : 3yqddtiapirm49ow
name                     : Environment: PYTHON=C:\Python35-x64, PYTHON_VERSION=3.5.x, PYTHON_ARCH=64
allowFailure             : False
messagesCount            : 0
compilationMessagesCount : 0
compilationErrorsCount   : 0
compilationWarningsCount : 0
testsCount               : 0
passedTestsCount         : 0
failedTestsCount         : 0
artifactsCount           : 1
status                   : success
started                  : 2017-03-23T08:37:08.5375578+00:00
finished                 : 2017-03-23T08:39:10.7684334+00:00
created                  : 2017-03-23T08:34:52.4856621+00:00
updated                  : 2017-03-23T08:39:10.7840711+00:00
```

I need `jobId` where name contains `Python35-X64`.

The following expression returns nothing, what am I doing wrong?

```
$job_id = $build.build.jobs | where { $_.name -like "*Python35-X64*" }
```

Comment: this should work, is that property a string?

Answer (score 1):

Your expression returns nothing because the result gets assigned to variable `$job_id`. The variable in this case does not contain the id of the job but the job object.

```
$job = $build.build.jobs |? name -like "*Python35-X64*" | Select-Object -First 1;
$job;
$job_id = $job.jobId;
```

Attention: If you do not select the first result the `$job` will contain an array of jobs in case that multiple names match the where clause.

In case you want to select the `jobId` attribute directly you can do so as follows.

```
$job_id = ($build.build.jobs |? name -like "*Python35-X64*" | Select-Object -First 1).jobId;
```

Comment: so why is this a thing? If i do this `$job_id = $build.build.jobs | where { $_.name -like "*Python35-X64*" }` it returns an array of objects containing 'Python35-x64'

Comment: @4c74356b41 I'm not sure if I properly understood your comment. I wrote the warning in my answer because the variable has name `$job_id` and if this variable should contain multiple Ids I would rename the variable to `$job_ids` so that not another programmer unexpectedly implies that there is always only exactly 1 id assigned.